# How to fetch git old versions with Jenkins

Tags: git, github, jenkins, continuous-integration

From Jenkins, I would like to fetch last but one commit code for deploying my application. I want this operation to be performed with Git client plugin but not with shell script. Is there a way to perform this operation.

Ex:- my current head version is pointing to 90696 and my old head version is at 38495. I would like to fetch head version of 38495.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$BRANCHNAME~1` to get one commit behind as your git plugin branch specifier. For head just use `HEAD~1`

E.g. on my jenkins file repo

```
git checkout feature/jenkins-pipelines~1
Note: checking out 'feature/jenkins-pipelines~1'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 7a4c357... updated jenkinsfile
```

Note that this works with any number given `HEAD~5` will be 5 commits behind head and so on.